# Loading images from the With with UIImage(named: )

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimage

I’m trying to use https://github.com/PhilippeBoisney/AlertOnboarding to load images from the web. I see AlertOnboarding uses UIImage(named: ) to load images and wants arrayOfImages as Strings from the user but I can’t seem to load images from the web as UIImage(named: “URLString of an image”). Nor do I have an option to download the image as NSData and then use UIImage(data: ) to show my image. What do I do?

Comment: are you load the image from server or local

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik It’s just a URL. From server.

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Comment: Here. let arrayOfImages = [“http://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/976/media/images/83351000/jpg/_83351965_explorer273lincolnshirewoldssouthpicturebynicholassilkstone.jpg”], which will be  UIImage(named: “http://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/976/media/images/83351000/jpg/_83351965_explorer273lincolnshirewoldssouthpicturebynicholassilkstone.jpg”) in AlertOnboardingViewController.

Comment: I call arrayOfImages as alertView = AlertOnboarding(arrayOfImage: arrayOfImages, arrayOfTitle: arrayOfTitle, arrayOfDescription: arrayOfDescription)

Comment: no no this is wrong, `AlertOnboarding` its loading the local image only, if you want the same you need to create the multiple image based on array count and add the image to array and follow the procedure

Comment: show ur tried code it is better to optimize

Comment: how do we create multiple image based on array count?

Comment: ok I tell the logic , you need to customize